# Geoserver ( Java.exe ) cause server to run 100%

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, java

Our server runs at 100% CPU when using map services build on geoserver + postgresql
I can not find anything in geoserver logs.

- It is Java.exe takes 100% CPU and because of that server can not do
  anything else until we restart geoserver.

Environment: Geoserver 2.5.1, PostgresSQL 9.3, SQL Server 2008 R2

Any suggestion what issue causing it to go 100%?

**Note/Solution: It was causing when we tried to project huge database native web Mercator into wgs84. we changed the source data back to wgs84 and it never went to 100% again**

Comment: look in the log file?

Comment: Have you take a look at [this post](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/production/index.html) in order to enhance the geoserver performances and even then to optimize the JVM?

Comment: I realize that this isn't very helpful, but this happens to us all the time. I have spent house/days looking in log files, tuning the JVM, etc, and ultimately have come up with no smoking gun. Every few days our geoservers just go to 100% cpu usage and need restarting. We have basically resorted to restarting them with a cron job at night, which "solves" the problem, but is a bit of a hack.

Comment: @JohnBarça - without a bug report there is very little the developers can do to help fix this. At a minimum we'd need to know what hardware, OS, geoserver version, data sets and the log files to fix.

Comment: @iant. I realize that. But it is hard to file a bug report without an obvious cause. I have plenty of command line Linux skills, and even though Tomcat logs tend towards the unabridged works of Shakespeare in volume, I would hope to be able to extract some cause from them -- and I have, so far, failed.

Comment: It was causing when we tried to project huge database native web Mercator into wgs84. we changed the source data back to wgs84 and it never went to 100% again.